# Adding/creating a click event for rows to a Vaadin Grid with SelectionMode.MULTI?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-grid

I am trying to create a small application where I have various file locations stored in a Vaadin grid, the grid currently only shows two columns - `ID` and `File Name`, and I would like to see as a notification the file location too whenever I click on a row.

Meaning, every time I click a row from the grid I would like it to show me the location, using `Notification.show()`, like that:

[image: rainbows] (Please ignore the `<b></b>`s, they are irrelevant.)

As my grids selection model is `MULTI`, per default the click listener cannot register which row it is clicked on and selecting the row via checkbox is not what I want to have the data displayed. Simply, I would like to get the item for every row I click and have the location displayed as a notification.

So far, I found a solution for a similar issue but it deals with columns and the rows in Vaadin grids are rather different from what I am used to.

```
public static <T> void addColumnClickListener(Grid<T> grid, Consumer<Column<T>> listener)
    {
        String expression = "function(){const col=element.getEventContext(event).column;return col ? col.id : '';}()";
        grid.getElement().addEventListener("click", e -> 
        {
            String colId = e.getEventData().getString(expression);
            Optional<Column<T>> column = grid.getColumns().stream().filter(col -> colId.equals(col.getId().get())).findFirst();
            column.ifPresent(listener);
        }
        ).addEventData(expression);
    }
```

And I am to call the function like that:

```
addColumnClickListener(grid, column -> Notification.show("fubar"));
```

This code snippet is from [the Vaadin forums](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17585345/get-the-grid-column-by-clicklistener) and I do not quite understand it. The string `expression` seems to be that it contains possible JavaScript code and the rest overrides the type of the column. *(I think, I really do not understand this snippet fully)*

Is there any way to do something similar to the snippet above but for rows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an ItemClickListener on the Grid:

```
grid.addItemClickListener(item -> {
    Notification.show(String.format("File location: %s", item.getLocation()));
});
```